# How i can show images in image gallery in MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-image-gallery

I want to show images get from database in a base64 form and show in image gallery. Please someone suggest me the image gallery and how i can show image dynamically.The count of images maybe 2,5,6,.. . I don't know the count of images. how i can show images in a bootstrap or other plugin with MVC 5?

Comment: Please try something first and post if you struck somewhere or post the code that you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below code it will replicate images from Model.
you can use Bootstrap Image Gallery

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Country)
    {
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,@(Convert.ToBase64String(item.Image))" alt="@item.CountryName" />
    }
```

Comment: The actual implementation is different but this helped me.